# how to clear the values in react-multiple-datepicker?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, reactjs, css

I am using react-multiple-datepicker.But I am not able to clear the values once assigned.
    import MultipleDatePicker from "react-multiple-datepicker";
    import React from "react";

```
class Addjob extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state ={
        selectedDays:[]
        };
        this.displayDates=this.displayDates.bind(this);
    }

    displayDates(dates) {
        console.log("selected dates:"+ dates);
        console.log(typeof dates);     
        dates.forEach(function(x) {
            var d = new Date(x),
            month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
            day = '' + d.getDate(),
            year = d.getFullYear();    
            if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
            if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
            console.log(year);
            console.log(day);
            console.log(month);
            y.push([year, month, day].join('-'));
            a=JSON.stringify(y);
            a=a.replace("[","");
            a=a.replace("]","");
            a=a.replace(/\"/g, "")  ; 
        });
        this.setState({selectedDays:a});
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <MultipleDatePicker className="multipicker" onSubmit={this.displayDates} id="multidatepicker"/>                                 
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide more code. how you are set date value ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this : 
- In Render:

```
 render() {
        return(
                <>
                    <MultipleDatePicker className="multipicker" onSubmit={this.displayDates} 
                             id="multidatepicker"/>
                    <Button onClick={(e)=>ClearDate(e)}>Clear</Button>       
                </>                 
        );
    }
```

and then function :

```
ClearDate = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   this.setState({selectedDays:[]});
}
```